# build errors when compiling in ac-docker win10 asking to rebuild compiled header since a file has been modified since the precompiled header

Tags: docker, windows-10, azerothcore

here is a copy of a few erros but the are to many to list in the post maybe 50 total all same error just different file names

```
fatal error: file '/azerothcore/src/server/game/Entities/GameObject/GameObject.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/azerothcore/var/build/obj/src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch' was built: size changed
note: please rebuild precompiled header '/azerothcore/var/build/obj/src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch'
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:154: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/CoreAI/GuardAI.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

how can i do this step and rebuild my precompiled headers in docker build of ac? also my world database keeps bloating up in size huge amounts went from 8gb to 16gb to 28 gb since most recent new build yesterday files from 10/11/2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is because of the ccache, which is the cache that allows you to have super-fast compilation, but sometime the header cache fails because of a high amount of changes, and it must be cleaned.

So, Please try this:

```
./acore.sh docker dev:dash compiler ccacheClean
```

it should clean the ccache, then you can restart the compilation

PS The problem about the database size is related to the configuration of MySQL. InnoDB usually stores a large amount of Binglogs that should be cleaned. But please open a separated question for that. AC provides the default MySQL configuration and the system admin should tune it based on its needs

Comment: so, i did a wipe and fresh install w/o the world database i saved, so i only imported the auth and char databases back into my build, have not had anymore issues until today nov. 6th when i did the git pull command to "update" my server, process completed, then i did the build command..... and now i have the same 50+ error or so asking to rebuild the precompiled headers. i used your command above for the ccacheClean, then rebuild and still i have the same issues, this did not fix the build errors as mentioned for precompiled headers to be rebuild.

Comment: the database is not involved with this error, that is 100% related to the ccache and the build folder. Both of them are under the /var folder of the project (but you need to access the docker console). Try to run both the `ccacheClean` and then run a `compiler all`

Comment: thank you for these commands! i ran both and it solved all the issues mentioned above. rebuilt my core with zero errors. ran server, everything seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i was able to fix my problems was at a personal cost to hours spent with creating so much custom content, only to be lost. i rebuilt a clean server and then only imported my AUTH and CHARACTER databases, problems solved. the build is 100% working as intended, but will have to slowly and painfully redo all my custom work that was done in the WORLD database.

Comment: that is why we advise keeping ALL your custom changes in SQL files stored somewhere so you can easily re-apply them on an AC clean world database. This has several benefits, other than having a backup of the changes.

Comment: also, check the answer from @Joseph which should solve the original issue